# Chaning DIR colors in Linux Terminal

Tags: linux, ssh

I am running **centos** and connecting through **SSH** with **PuTTY**, I have read in multiple threads now that changing colors can be done in

```
nano /etc/bashrc
nano /etc/DIR_COLORS
```

At default the color is blue, I am trying to change to magneta which is apparently color code **35**

within **nano /etc/DIR_COLORS** I have located and altered the following.

```
DIR 01;35
```

After this I try to reload via

```
source /etc/profile
source /etc/bashrc
```

When running **ls /etc** I see directories are still dark blue.

Another concerning matter is when leaving both **bashrc** and **DIR_COLORS** files default, when I run source /etc/bashrc then ls /etc the DIR text is not bold, when I run source /etc/profile then source /etc/bashrc the text goes back to bold.

What is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making it `.dir_colors`. I don't know if that makes a difference.

You could also try adding `eval $(dircolors -b /etc/.dir_colors)` to your /etc/bashrc. This will set your LS_COLORS environment variable based on your `.dir_colors` file.